# java listFiles() to return files only

Tags: java

I noticed that the `listFiles()` method returns files as well as directories, however I'd like to fill my array `filePath` with files only. I know there's an `isFile()` method but I don't know how to combine it with `listFiles()` to achieve what I want.

I found some similar questions but they're about applying a filter on extensions while I have no particular file extension in mind.

Thanks in advance! :)

Example code:

```
File f = new File (path);
File [] filePath;
filePath = f.listFiles(); // how to modify this to get files only?
```

Comment: Loop over your `File[]` and check for each if `isFile()` Add it to a new `List`

Comment: @gtgaxiola woops I should've been more precise! I wanted to add all files directly to my array without knowing its size beforehand or creating a list and then another array from that. I was looking for a simple way to add only files directly to my array, as davidxxx has provided such a solution. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `File` API :

```
File f = new File (path);
File [] files = f.listFiles(File::isFile);
```

With `Path` API that is better designed you could write:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(path);
List<Path> path =
    Files.list(dir)
         .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or to work directly with the stream of `Path` :

```
Path dir = Paths.get(path);
Files.list(dir)
     .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
     .forEach(p -> doSomethingWithP);
```